# Inject a factory in a controller in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I´m trying to inject a factory in a controller in Angular, but I can not do. It is my code.

> app.controller('ManejadorEventosVista', ['AdministradorMarcador', ManejadorEventosVista]);

'app' is the variable that corresponds to the module with their respective dependencies. The controller is 'ManejadorEventosVista' and requires the services provided by the factory 'AdministradorMarcador'.

> function ManejadorEventosVista(){}

but when I want to use the factory 'AdministradorMarcador' in this part of the code , the factory is not recognized.

> ManejadorEventosVista.prototype.seleccionarMarcadorOrigen = function (){
>      AdministradorMarcador.setTipoMarcador(AdministradorMarcador.MARCADOR_ORIGEN);
>   };

How I can do to use the factory
 'AdministradorMarcador' in ManejadorEventosVista.prototype.seleccionarMarcadorOrigen??..

Help or example to guide me??..Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

`ManejadorEventosVista` needs to take an argument and you will be able to reference the `AdministradorMarcador` inside the function as whatever you named the first variable. Like so

```
function ManejadorEventosVista(AdministradorMarcador){/**your code here**/}
```

What you are doing with the line fragment `['AdministradorMarcador', ManejadorEventosVista]` is declaring that your function depends on `AdministradorMarcador`, but without providing an argument to `ManejadorEventosVista`, AngularJS doesn't know how you intend to reference `AdministradorMarcador` inside your controller.

This is done in order to allow AngularJS scripts to be minified, especially by already existing solutions, as they would change the variables your function takes to single letter names, making it impossible for AngularJS to determine which service or factory to inject. Annotation uses strings and position-based ordering to allow your script to work, even after being minified since strings won't be altered by the process.

See also [Latest Stable docs on Annotation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/docs/guide/di#dependency-annotation)

Comment: Thanks..it is right and works but i need use the factory 'AdministradorMarcador' as shown in the following code: line 1: 'app.controller('ManejadorEventosVista', ['AdministradorMarcador', ManejadorEventosVista]);' , line 2: var ManejadorEventosVista = function (AdministradorMarcador){}; , line 3: ManejadorEventosVista.prototype.seleccionarMarcadorDestino = function (){AdministradorMarcador.setTipoMarcador(AdministradorMarcador.MARCADOR_DESTINO);};

Comment: the problem is that inside ManejadorEventosVista.prototype.seleccionarMarcadorDestino i can not used the factory AdministradorMarcador, it is not recognized and i need this for use in the event of a button in the view and thus not use the scope in the controller

Comment: I could solve the problem, with the following code: "function ManejadorEventosVista(AdministradorMarcador){
    this.admMarcador = AdministradorMarcador;
}" , and so I could use AdministradorMarcador in "ManejadorEventosVista.prototype.seleccionarMarcadorOrigen = function (){ this.admMarcador.setTipoMarcador(this.admMarcador.MARCADOR_ORIGEN);
};"